# Incorrect export of highchart graph

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, scale

I am having problems with exporting highcharts graphs. Basically, in the default settings, all the charts look absolutely weird, they are either too big, part of the legend is missing, parts overlap etc.

I therefore looked into the documentation for highcharts and found that I probably need to play around with the three parameters, the width, height and scale. But, no matter how long I tried it and what combinations I used, I never get the graph right and it never looks as the one I actually finally see rendered on the webpage.

I would really like for it to look like the one I have on the webpage as it would save me plenty of time and I wouldnt have to do it by printscreen.

Here is on example:

So my page is here:
http://meteopage.com/eng/console/console_day.php?den=1&mesic=1&rok=2015

First have a look at for example the "humidity graph" - this one has no parameters set, i.e. it uses the default setting of highcharts. As you can see, the image is magnified, part of the legend is missing etc.

Then look at the "temperature graph" - this is the one I tried to play around with and what you see is the best result I was able to get, but still, what always remains wrong no matter what size or scale I set, is that the legend is overlapping. And even if I make the whole image bigger or change the scale, the legend also changes size and always remains overlaping.

The code I used for this particular example to achieve this, which was the best I was able to is:

```
sourceWidth: 1860,
sourceHeight: 400,
scale: 1,
```

And finally just for completeness, here is the documentation for the module:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting

I would very much appreciate any help if someone could told me what to do so that I get graphs which look like the ones I see in the browser...

Thanks

Comment: Well on humidity chart I see correct, nothing is cutted, so please let me know which browser do you use ?

Comment: well I figured out how to do it, I made changes to the exporting script and now it asks me for each graph for the dimensions and scale and one must just use the trial/error method

Comment: So problem is solved, right ?

Comment: Well, sort of, it is not ideal, but right now it asks me for the dimensions and I can quickly try to find the best option without having to change the code.